# NFS share from DSM cannot use on PVE

Tags: nfs, debian-based, proxmox

I'm currently using a Proxmox platform (Basicly Debian in the problem), and i'd like to use a nfs share from DSM (Synology) to store backups and iSOs.

The DSM is also a VM in that platform, linked with the host by a linux bridge that bond with a interface.

Current problem is that, although the PVE webui can show the NFS storage, and touch can create file  in that storage, `rsync -avh /originStorage/template/iso/debian.qcow2 /NFS-DSM/template/iso/ --progress` will stuck after 100% progress. and the `-vvv` shows stuck at `server_recv(2) starting`

The stuck cannot be recovered by `ctrl-c`. I mean, the rsync seems stopped at first. But after a while there are output on stdout stats that `rsync stuck over ** seconds`. The output only stops after full reboot. Soft reboot i.e., `root@host reboot` or reboot from web ui, will be stuck by rsync, and output will not proceed.

Please any one with relative experience help me figure it out.

configs:
[image: NFS setting on PVE]
[image: NFS share setting on DSM]

bold translate: squash all to admin, permission: read and write

cmdline tried `cp`, `rsync` basicly the same.

tried squash non, squash root to admin, basicly the same